# What other installations is Pokemon White compatible with?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Other than **Pokemon: Black Version**, I am curious to know what other Pokemon games can be used to trade Pokemon with my version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any 5th Generation Pokemon game is compatible with any of the other 3 5th generation games (So White, Black 2, and White 2, in your case).

While you can't trade directly, it is also possible to (albeit, one way) transfer Pokemon from any of the 5 4th generation games (Diamond, Pearl, Platinum, HeartGold, SoulSilver) to Pokemon Black.

Since 4th generation games themselves can do a one-way transfer of pokemon from the 3rd gen, it is possible to bring pokemon from even Ruby, Sapphire, and Emerald into pokemon Black.